# Python and Django - assigning fields in dict instead of overwriting?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I'm using a Python dict to map strings to Django fields. I want to update, or assign the value of the fields as so.

```py
self.sheet_headers_2_fields = {
    'Index': self.index,
    'Device Model': self.model,
    'MAC address': self.mac_address,
    'IP Address': self.ip_address,
}

for sheet_header, model_field in self.sheet_headers_2_fields.items():
    model_field = item.get_field_value(sheet_header)
```

I'm using the dict to make it easier to map strings to fields should more fields be added. Currently, this just overwrites model_field, instead of assigning it to the corresponding field, and thus, the model is not updated.

Why does this not work? I know that Python passes by reference - my guess is that because `model_field` (A django field) is not the same type a `item.get_field_value(sheet_header)` (a str), it overwrites to a reference instead of updating the value.

How can I achieve what I want, either with a dict, or some other method?

Comment: `overwrites instead of updating the value.` -- Exactly. Try with `self.sheet_headers_2_fields[sheet_header] = item.get_field_value(sheet_header)`

Comment: If all you need is to have the updated values in the dict `self.sheet_headers_2_fields` but not reflected in the target fields `self.index`, `self.model`, etc., then the answer from @bdbd is all you need. But if you need to update the target fields as well, then some additional code is needed as `self.sheet_headers_2_fields[sheet_header] = item.get_field_value(sheet_header)` only updates the dict.

Answer (score 1):

When you performed this:

```
self.sheet_headers_2_fields = {
    'Index': self.index,
    'Device Model': self.model,
    'MAC address': self.mac_address,
    'IP Address': self.ip_address,
}
```

Those `self.index`, `self.model`, etc. are not stored as references, but rather you put their values into the dict.

So let's say:

```
self.index = 1
self.model = 2
self.mac_address = 3
self.ip_address = 4
```

Then it translates to:

```
self.sheet_headers_2_fields = {
    'Index': 1,
    'Device Model': 2,
    'MAC address': 3,
    'IP Address': 4,
}
```

With that said, `model_field = item.get_field_value(sheet_header)` wouldn't work especially for fields that are immutable (e.g. `str`) because those type of objects would just be overwritten every time (which means at some point, our connection to `self.attr` will already be lost).

- But if the field is mutable e.g. `list`, then of course list operations e.g. `append` (be aware not to use equal `=` operations as that would point your stack variable to a different heap storage thus losing access to `self.attr`) would target the exact same object. Overwriting wouldn't happen thus you should see it reflect on your fields.

### Alternative Solution: Usage of [setattr](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#setattr)

Instead of mapping e.g. `self.mac_address`, just map the name `"mac_address"` and then use `setattr` to update that field.

```
class MyModel:
    def __init__(self):
        self.index = None
        self.model = None
        self.mac_address = None
        self.ip_address = None

        self.sheet_headers_2_fields = {
            'Index': 'index',
            'Device Model': 'model',
            'MAC address': 'mac_address',
            'IP Address': 'ip_address',
        }

        for sheet_header, model_field in self.sheet_headers_2_fields.items():
            setattr(self, model_field, item.get(sheet_header))  # This now translates to e.g. self.mac_address = item.get("MAC address")

item = {
    'Index': 1,
    'Device Model': 'ABC123',
    'MAC address': '1A-2B-3C-4D-5E-6F',
    'IP Address': '127.0.0.1',
}

obj = MyModel()
print(f"{obj.sheet_headers_2_fields=}")
print(f"{obj.index=}")
print(f"{obj.model=}")
print(f"{obj.mac_address=}")
print(f"{obj.ip_address=}")
```

Output:

```
obj.sheet_headers_2_fields={'Index': 'index', 'Device Model': 'model', 'MAC address': 'mac_address', 'IP Address': 'ip_address'}
obj.index=1
obj.model='ABC123'
obj.mac_address='1A-2B-3C-4D-5E-6F'
obj.ip_address='127.0.0.1'
```

Comment: Glad it helped :) If it's all the answer that you are finding, you might want to accept it as the correct answer https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers otherwise leave it as is :)